# Frequency Distribution from Data frame in R

Tags: r

I'm sorry if this is a basic question but is it possible to create a frequency distribution from a data table like:

```
               Town 1        Town 1        Town 2     Town 2     Town 3
Fish            Yes            Yes          Yes       No          No
Crops           No             No           Yes       No          Yes
Livestock       Yes            Yes          No        No          Yes
```

Where the frequency distribution shows the frequency of each Place per variable?

*edit*

Thank you to those who answered, you're right, it's better if I put some actual data.
Okay, this is pretty close to my original data. As you can see, the Towns are not unique (since this is from a survey of people living in the towns). So I was hoping to sum the frequency of each product(Fish, Crops, Livestock,etc.) over each town and eventually plot it as a pie graph/histogram.

Something like:

```
                Town 1       Town 2       Town 3
 Fish             2            1            0
 Crops            0            1            1
 Livestock        2            0            1
```

Though I think this would appear better as percentages? Anyway thank you for any help you send my way, I don't know anyone experienced with R so I'm kind of going around this blindly.

Comment: Are you looking for something like `library(reshape2); data.frame(table(melt(as.matrix(mydf))))` or `library(reshape2); table(melt(as.matrix(mydf)))` perhaps? It would be good if you can edit your question to show your desired output with this small example.

Comment: Yes thank you @AnandaMahto for the comment, I edited the data! Would reshape work even with repeated column names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on my comment, let's start with some reproducible sample data:

```
mydf <- data.frame(item = c("fish", "crops", "ls"),
                   T1 = c("Y", "N", "Y"),
                   T1 = c("Y", "N", "Y"),
                   T2 = c("Y", "Y", "N"),
                   T2 = c("N", "N", "N"),
                   T3 = c("N", "Y", "Y"), check.names = FALSE)
mydf
#    item T1 T1 T2 T2 T3
# 1  fish  Y  Y  Y  N  N
# 2 crops  N  N  Y  N  Y
# 3    ls  Y  Y  N  N  Y
```

`melt` from "reshape2" will not work nicely with the repeated column names, so make them unique first.

```
names(mydf) <- ave(names(mydf), names(mydf), 
                   FUN = function(x) paste0(x, "_", seq_along(x)))
```

Now, proceed similar to I had suggested:

```
library(reshape2)
x <- melt(mydf, id.vars="item_1")  ## Melt the dataset
xY <- x[x$value == "Y", ]          ## Subset just "Y" values
## Tabulate
table(xY$item_1, sapply(strsplit(as.character(xY$variable), "_"), "[[", 1))
#        
#         T1 T2 T3
#   crops  0  1  1
#   fish   2  1  0
#   ls     2  0  1
```

Comment: Thank you @AnandaMahto!!! This worked for me! Thank you for helping me figure out how to deal with duplicated names.

Comment: @James, the output of `table` is already a `matrix`, so assign the output of table to an object, say, "tableout", and then just use `barplot(tableout, beside = TRUE)`.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood your question right

```
# constructing your data frame
df <- data.frame(v1=c(1,0,1),v2=c(0,0,1),v3=c(1,1,0))
rownames(df) <- c('p1','p2','p3')

# calculating the distributions
t(t(df)/apply(df,2,sum))
```

Comment: Damn I'm sorry, I forgot my data frame is in Yes/No. Is it still possible to do that?

Comment: You mean they are saved as TRUE/FALSE? In this case it works as i supposed. For a `sum` a TRUE is converted to 1, a FALSE to 0.

Comment: Strangely no, they are only saved as characters. Is there a way to convert them into the TRUE/FALSE factors?

Comment: Oh actually t(t(df=='Yes')/apply(df=='Yes',2,sum)) did, I did get NaN as in some columns, can I just disregard them?

Comment: In this case you should replace them depending on your needs by a Yes or No in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use `table`:

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- table(paste('Place',sample(1:3,10,rep=T),sep='_'),
      paste('Variable',sample(1:3,10,rep=T),sep='_'))

          Variable_1 Variable_2 Variable_3
  Place_1          1          0          2
  Place_2          1          1          2
  Place_3          0          2          1
```

**EDIT**

```
ifelse(dat>0,'Yes','No')

        Variable_1 Variable_2 Variable_3
  Place_1 "Yes"      "No"       "No"      
  Place_2 "Yes"      "Yes"      "Yes"     
  Place_3 "Yes"      "No"       "Yes"
```

Comment: Very sorry, forgot my data is in Yes/No answers. I already edited the original question

Comment: @James I edit my answer. But you should edit your answer and give an example of your input data ( Variable's, Places's,..)